# undefined offset 1 when trying to import csv file in database

Tags: php, csv

i am trying import csv file in database but it showing undefined offset 1 and it storing values in db as

```
 ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿRoot Entryÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
```

i don't know why.i was trying to fix that error from past 5 hours but i coudn't 
here is my code

```
<body>


<form name="import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
 <?php
include ("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $c = 0;
    $filesop = array();
    while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
    {
        $name = $filesop[0];
        $email = $filesop[1];
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mdl_user (username, email) VALUES 
       ('$name','$email')");
        $c = $c + 1;
     }

        if($sql){
            echo "You database has imported successfully. You have inserted 
   ". $c ." recoreds";
        }else{
            echo "Sorry! There is some problem.";
        }

  }
 ?>


 </body>
```

it showing undefined offset 1 error in this line

```
$email = $filesop[1];
```

can anyone help me

thanks in advance..

Comment: before doing $email = $filesop[1]; put an isset for $filesop[1] because $filesop[1] is not set and in the else of isset pass an empty string or whatever seems OK to you

Comment: how can we add isset for email

Comment: What does that csv file contain?

Comment: only 2 records in excel one is username in a column and one is email in b clumn

Comment: not adding isset for email..adding isset for $filesop[1]

Comment: like this right? isset($filesop[1]) ? $filesop[1] : null;